# Getting Image from Page Link for django application

Tags: python, json, django, beautifulsoup

I have json file and it contain

"Product_url": "https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Galaxy-Storage-Additional-Exchange/dp/B07PQ7CRBH/ref=sr_1_11?keywords=phone&qid=1563166792&s=electronics&smid=A14CZOWI0VEHLG&sr=1-11",

**How to get image from this
like below one**

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ftMiKUwbL._SL1500.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this question in two ways.

One, if you just want to display the image on a template then simply use the `src` attribute of the `img` element and set that `URL`

Secondly, if you want to pass the image from your `views.py` to the template then follow the method here - [How can I pass an image to a template in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645938/how-can-i-pass-an-image-to-a-template-in-django)

The `URL` of the image is sufficient. In your relevant `views.py` method add a request call to the URL and download the image and pass the data as context, example call below.

```
import requests

url = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ftMiKUwbL._SL1500.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("/Users/apple/Desktop/sample.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: How to get image URL from page  is my concern.Sorry, i didn't get in your above answer.

Comment: You'd need to scrape the page to obtain the image url, using bs4 or headless selenium.

Comment: Or also you can use the `Amazon` library to get the image `URL` give the product Id - see this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269803/get-all-image-urls-from-amazon-api)

Comment: @bishwas Have you solved it? If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information